# Can we control number of consumers in a consumer group through code in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Can we control the number of consumers in a consumer group through code in Kstream application?

In my application, I have 8 instances with 20 threads each, how many consumers will be created in my consumer group?

Kafka topic partitions = 480

Will it be 8 instances * 20 threads = 160 consumers?

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural. It's not a numbered list of questions site. If you have multiple questions, each needs to be in a separate post, and should always contain more information in the post body than what is in the title. You may want to review [ask]. If you need clarification of how the site works, you can find that information in the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You control the number of threads in one application

And you control the number of instances by running the application process in parallel (JAR, Docker, etc).

Yes, you multiply them together to get total consumers per `application.id`, although, Kafka Streams can be consuming multiple topics at once, not all with the same partition count